# Why does os.execvp block on apache but not on the shell?

Tags: python

I'm looking for a way, in plain python (no extra libraries) to kick off a background process that will run after the web page returns.

In the shell, this script below exits, and then prints "Hello World". However, in the browser, it blocks until two.py is finished.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import sys

def run():
    program = "python"
    pid = os.fork()
    if not pid:
        os.execvp(program, (program,"two.py"))

run()

print "Content-type: text/html"
print ""
print "Hello, World!"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think this is because Apache is not waiting on your process, but on your whole process group.

When you `fork` a new process, it inherits your process group. And `exec` doesn't change that. If you want to force it to detach, you have to do so explicitly, e.g., by using [`setpgrp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.setpgrp):

```
pid = os.fork()
if not pid:
    os.setpgrp()
    os.execvp(program, (program,"two.py"))
```

Depending on your platform, this may also mean it gets a new session, meaning it no longer has a controlling terminal, but I don't think you care about that.

---

However, it might be a better design to rewrite `two.py` using the [`daemon`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) library. Then, no matter how you spawn it, it'll take care of daemonizing *itself*. Run it your script or directly, from Apache, or the shell, in the background, whatever, it will never make anyone wait for it, get tangled up with a terminal, zombify, etc.

Comment: The daemonize worked....I could have saved myself lots of time by doing this as a shell script. But meh...now I have this recipe for life!